# AS3 - Event dispatch not picked up

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to do an eventDispatch but the event isn't getting picked up.
The dispatch is coming from swf B, and the listener is in swf A.

Not sure if it's an issue because they are 2 files. Does anyone know of a solution?

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Code samples would be helpful. What event type are you trying to dispatch? What is the relationship between swf A and swf B?

Comment: you could post some code perhaps? are you listening on swf B's instance?

Comment: 5 bucks says it's an event bubbling issue.

Comment: Might be an applicationdomain issue as well.

Comment: Hi Roy, how do I resolve application domain issue? Do I need to load in crossdomain.xml or something?

Answer (score 1):

If the communication is between two SWFs that are not loaded into the same container SWF then a local connection must be used to facilitate communication between them.  If they are in the same construct, ie SWF A loads SWF B into itself, then make sure you are instantiating the listener through the container it loads into, something like someContainer.SWF_B.addEventListener(...  that's my best guess without some code posted.

Comment: Hey Ribs, so basically I have main.swf that loads in a.swf and b.swf. Then I have a Singleton eventdispatcher class that I'm using to facilitate the eventdispatcher stuff. So from b.swf I have SingletonED.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("COMPLETE")); And in a.swf I have MyObject.addEventListener("COMPLETE", func); func is currently not receiving the dispatched event.

Comment: try `SingletonED.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("COMPLETE", true));`

Comment: Thanks weltaumpirat, yeah I just tried that bubbling per your suggestion. Still no luck.

Comment: ok so main loads A and B.  Straight to main's display list or are you adding them to the display list of a container movieclip?  Are the loaded swfs higher player versions than main? (might not be an issue but I have had issues related to that before).  Are the loaded swfs and main all AS3?  in the above example, is "myObject" derived from the loader content?

Comment: Hi Ribs, so main.swf loads a.swf & b.swf and I addChild those in some predetermined holder mc under main.swf. The addEventListener actually lives within a MC under b.swf that I make a class ResultTout.as. Then a.swf invoke a Singleton class called ExternalData.as which is the one that dispatch the event using the SingletonED class. Both a.swf & b.swf are verified to have been loaded when the dispatch event is fired.

Comment: hmmm..  something like ResultTout.SingletonED.addEventListener(...   that's how I am understanding the listener should be instantiated based on what I am reading. Of course you'd use whatever instance names you associated with the instances of those classes, ResultTout and SingletonED.  Again just sorta guessing around here.

Comment: The `SingletonED` instance must be a descendant of b.swf, and b.swf must be a descendant of `MyObject`. Make sure this is correct.  Also, your program would be more easy to understand if you kept to naming conventions: Instance, variable and method names should start with a lower case character. Only interface and class names should start with an upper case character.